# Running Android UI in JVM

Tags: java, android, swing, user-interface

I am looking for a library / framework that lets me develop Java UIs (e.g., for Windows) using the Android views, layouts and animations. Things like a message loop and AsyncTask would be a great bonus. I don't want to run an emulator but simply get a jar-file.

Unfortunately, my google-foo is insufficient for this task.

Kind regards,
Volker

Comment: An implementation of the Java API for standard JRE, interesting idea. There are some things that are specific for mobile devices but then, Android is running on all kind of devices nowadays, including netbook like devices. So with the expected restrictions (e.g. typically no touch input) it could be possible.

Comment: Basic support should not be too difficult. All system services but the layout inflater simply return null. Broadcastreceivers are only called for events that can happen on the maschine, but all can register. And so on...
The GUI framework must have been partially ported for the emulators. I simply need a library that I can include in stand-alone software. And I really hope someone else already did the work :)

Comment: For the _emulator_? I don't think so, those are basically VMs. Do you think of the IDE support for UI creation?

Answer (score 1):

The project [IcedRobot](https://github.com/icedrobot) has the goal to develop such a framework. But unfortunately it seems to be stuck - announced in 2011 and no updates for 2 years now.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please don't use answers to post question-comments, notices, info, etc. Use comments instead.

Comment: This seems more appropriate for a comment, since it doesn't provide a solution to the question.

Comment: [IcedRobot](https://github.com/icedrobot) exists and actually provides source code. May be it solves the above problem or it makes sense for the original questioner to participate in order to achieve this. From my knowledge it's the only project that is directed to run the Android Application stack at the "standard" JRE/OpenJDK. In this effect: it's the correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is and will have such thing. Be able running android view system requires not only the java file but lot other native library such as SurfaceFlinger.

Comment: Of course it needs native libraries, otherwise I could simply use the Android SDK ;)
The emulator runs on windows and is able to receive mouse and keyboard inputs. For now, that is all I need. I just need it as a library that I can include in other projects. I am just wondering if anyone has already done all the boring work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as Android java is not standard java and doesn't run on `JavaVM` but rather on `DalvikVM`.

Take a look at this question:

[DalvikVM Vs JavaVM in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536786/dalvikvm-vs-javavm-in-android)

Comment: Volker asks specifically for the UI layer, not for running binaries.

Comment: I don't want to run a compiled .apk under Windows. I asked if someone already ported the required GUI libraries so that I can use them when writing a normal Java program.

Comment: BTW: each Android app is first compiled into JavaVM byte code and then crosscompiled into DalvikVM byte code. The reason you cannot simply run that first byte code is that you do not have the native libraries that the Android UI links to.