# What is process, thread, sandbox and DalvikVM instance in android?

Tags: android

What is process, thread, sandbox and DalvikVM instance in android?

Comment: They are all nouns. Beyond that, please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: sorry I agree my questions is not so specific, if I can know the sequential order they are created, and the dependencies they have, if any?

Comment: can you help me with the sequential order they are created and what are the instances of Dalvik VM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a simple explantion on the terms.

**Process -** Every application runs as a seperate process in the android device. For example, if you click on Messaging application on android device, a seperate stack is created for this application and all the activities (screens) you navigate in messaging application will be put in that stack. So, if you exit the application and return back to it, you can see the application in the same state you left it. This is because all its data are in a seperate stack. This is called process.

**Thread -** One process can have multiple threads. All UI rendering will be done in main thread. Any long running operation like network call happen in other threads.

**Sandbox -** Every application in the android device runs in a seperate compartment. No application can access other application's data without proper permission. It is a security mechanism android OS provides for its application.

**Dalvik VM -** Simialr to a Java VM where java based applications can run, in android we have a seperate VM. Dalvik VM helps the applications run better in resource limited environment like mobile devices. Android java code will be converted to dalvik dex files (not like java exe files). To run this DEX files, we need Dalvik VM.

Comment: thanks prem, very informative.

Comment: also what are the instances of Dalvik VM is it another name for sandbox?

Comment: @eMM, Sandoxing is a concept of running applications as a separate closed box. Dalvik VM is the layer on which android applications run. Read this link to understand why we go for Dalvik VM and what are its advantages. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536786/dalvikvm-vs-javavm-in-android